# Appcenter / Fastlane error with React Native Android release

Tags: react-native, circleci, fastlane, visual-studio-app-center

I recently updated my project to the latest version of Appcenter (v. 3.1.1) and now my Android CircleCI pipeline is failing (but publishes the iOS app to app center without errors).

This is the error I get when I run it through fastlane:

```sh
[21:29:32]: Upload finished
[21:29:32]: Waiting for release to be ready...
[21:30:36]: Error fetching release: A problem occured while extracting your app. (Correlation ID: fdb816e8-5539-45ae-bb9a-a877272ec67b)
+-------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                             Lane Context                                                             |
+-------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ENVIRONMENT                         | prod                                                                                           |
| PLATFORM_NAME                       | android                                                                                        |
| LANE_NAME                           | android appcenter                                                                              |
| GRADLE_BUILD_TYPE                   | releaseStaging                                                                                 |
| GRADLE_ALL_APK_OUTPUT_PATHS         | ["/home/circleci/project/android/app/build/outputs/apk/releaseStaging/app-releaseStaging.apk"] |
| GRADLE_ALL_AAB_OUTPUT_PATHS         | []                                                                                             |
| GRADLE_ALL_OUTPUT_JSON_OUTPUT_PATHS | ["/home/circleci/project/android/app/build/outputs/apk/releaseStaging/output.json"]            |
| GRADLE_ALL_MAPPING_TXT_OUTPUT_PATHS | []                                                                                             |
| GRADLE_APK_OUTPUT_PATH              | /home/circleci/project/android/app/build/outputs/apk/releaseStaging/app-releaseStaging.apk     |
| GRADLE_OUTPUT_JSON_OUTPUT_PATH      | /home/circleci/project/android/app/build/outputs/apk/releaseStaging/output.json                |
+-------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[21:30:36]: Failed to upload release
```

Edit: This is what my `Fastfile` looks like:

```
desc "Upload to AppCenter"
  private_lane :upload_to_appcenter do | options |
    appcenter_upload(
      owner_name: owner_name,
      app_name: "MyAppName-Android",
      api_token: options[:api_token],
      destinations: "MyAppNameTesters",
      notify_testers: true,
      release_notes: "./CHANGELOG.md"
    )
  end
```

Comment: Doesn't really look like a problem with App Center

Comment: On a second thought, let me discuss it with backend team

Comment: @aditi could you paste the command you're running? obviously scrubbing out any sensitive params with "**" or something.

Comment: @JonPhenow I updated the post with my Fastfile commands.

Comment: @DmitriiChichuk I updated the post with a longer error message if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I added the following to my `app/build.gradle` and successfully uploaded my app to app center:

```
def appCenterSdkVersion = '3.3.0'
implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-crashes:${appCenterSdkVersion}"
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like we aren't able to extract any of: build version (version code), unique identifier (package), and minimum OS (SDK) version. Can you verify that those things are set in the manifest that's in your upload?

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: That's great! Glad you were able to get unblocked